# Run a For loop then stop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to click on this button and every time the button is clicked, 1 is added but when it gets to 12 I would like it to stop no matter if you continue to click on the button. Here is what I got so far.

```
<button>Click Me</button>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('button').click(function(){
            for ( var i = 0; i <= 12; i = i + 1 ) {
                console.log(i.val()+1);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I think what you want to achive dont need for loop. Just create i as global variable and increment on every button hit. check the variable value on every click and perform the operation till the value is reached.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

like

```
jQuery(function () {
    var counter = 0;
    $('button').on('click.counter', function () {
        if (++counter == 12) {
            $(this).off('click.counter')
        }
        console.log(counter)
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/yrbEL/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
    var t=0;
    $('button').click(function(){
        t = t+1;
        if(t>12){              
           return true;
        }
        console.log(t);

    });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/z8m7d/

Comment: you should start it with 1 and end with less than equal to 12. because user asking that his loop should stop after getting 12. Example: $('button').click(function(){
        for ( var i = 1; i <= 12; i++ ) {
            console.log(i);
        }
    });

Comment: @KrishR- the op is looking to allow the button to be clicked 12 times... not loop 12 times inside of one click.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a break point as follows :

```
 $('button').click(function(){
    for ( var i = 0; i <= 12; i++ )
    {
           if(i==12)
             {
       break;  // breaks out of loop completely
             }
        console.log(i);
    }
});
```

This would totally throw the code out of the for loop when the value comes to 12.

Comment: @RamMehta- the op is looking to allow the button to be clicked 12 times... not loop 12 times inside of one click.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is, once you reach 12 count then DISABLE the Button. So, user will not be able to click it after 12....

Answer (score 0):

```
var t=0;
$('button').click(function(){
     if(t++>=12){              
       return true;
    }
});
```